# How to add additional actions to command

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0, command

I am inheriting from a window control that already handles the `ApplicationCommands.Close` command so that it handles closing the window natively.

I would like to add/override the existing functionality, however I cannot seem to figure out how to do this.

Tried:

- Adding another of the same command to `CommandBindings` (first declared seems to win)
- Check if the command is already existing...Cannot seem to find a way to do this

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can try. If you are just trying to prevent your window from closing, you can override the `OnClosing` method and set the cancelled flag:

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

If you want to specifically alter the behavior, you can register with preview versions of the command:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"
                    PreviewExecuted="CloseCommandHandler"
                    PreviewCanExecute="CanExecuteHandler" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

The preview routed events will happen before the standard events, allowing you to handle the logic before your base class.

Comment: Yah, I am indeed trying that and figured I might have to go with the Closing event. I can't use preview because of this bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281825/routeduicommand-previewexecuted-bug  I feel like this problem could crop up again, so I am going to leave it open in the hopes for an answer to my actual question. Still +1

Comment: That seems like a nasty bug. I just cracked it open in reflector, and in .NET 4.5 at least, unless you set e.Handled = true in the preview event handler, the normal handler will still get called. So, depending on the version of .NET you're on, this may work!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace functionality of the global command, you can find the specific command binding, remove it then add your own logic. See below.

```
    public ChildWindow()
        :base()
    {
        var appCloseCommandBinding =
            CommandBindings.Cast<CommandBinding>().SingleOrDefault(item => item.Command == ApplicationCommands.Close);

        if(appCloseCommandBinding != null)
            CommandBindings.Remove(appCloseCommandBinding);

        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Close, YourCommandLogic));
    }
```

Hope it can help.